# Login failing for Google+ when tried form app

Tags: ios, google-plus, ipod-touch

In my application for iOS, I am having Google+ signin which works normally. But it is failing when the native Google+ app is installed in device.

If the Google+ application is not installed in the device, the login takes place through web and works fine. If installed, the signin takes place through this installed native app.

I am using the GPPSignIn APIs to authenticate. The Google document I referred for implementation is https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Error I am getting is - "error in signin Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)""

```
 -(IBAction)handleTapOnGooglePlus:(id)sender {
 if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) { 
       [self showProgressHUDWithText:@"Signing Out"];
       [self signOut];
     } else {
       [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
       [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].attemptSSO = YES;
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Shashank

Comment: HTTP 400 indicates it's a bad request. Are you sure it's being sent in the same way? Does the Google+ application expect something different?

Comment: We are using [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate] and it redirects to login screen.

Comment: Can you share the code that is making the request?

Comment: We are following the steps mentioned in the link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in                            -(IBAction)handleTapOnGooglePlus:(id)sender
{ 
 if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication])
 {
  [self showProgressHUDWithText:@"Signing Out"];
  [self signOut];
 }
 else
 {
  [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
        [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].attemptSSO = YES;
 }
}

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, but I am not getting any error, because once when app switches control to G+ app it never comes back to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have GPPSignInDelegate included in your interface file. Then try this.

```
-(IBAction)handleTapOnGooglePlus:(id)sender
 {
  if ([GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication)
            { 
                NSLog(@"Already authenticated");
            }
            else
            {
                [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]signOut];
                 [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].delegate=self;
                [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]authenticate];

            }

 }
```

Handle Callback here

```
-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
{

        [[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:[GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"] completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPerson *person, NSError *error)
         {
             if(error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Google Plus Error:%@",error.localizedDescription]);

             }
             else
             {

               NSLog(@"Authenticated");

         }];


}
```